# how to automate a flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, automated-tests, qtp

I have a Flex Application that needs to be automated using tools like HP's QuickTest Pro (QTP) or something. However, QTP requires that you write some custom code if you wish to automate some home-made components... Unfortunately, we have some 3rd-party components which we do not have the source code so we can't really the custom code without having the 3rd-party component's source code  and we cannot add some additional SWC files or some other files into the application to automate it. the application is already compiled and we have only the executable file.

Is there any existing framework and/or tools that would allow me to automate testing without having to write custom code that could be used by a non-programmer

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you're stuck.  FlexMonkey and RIATest are two alternatives to QTP, however you're going to run into the same exact issues you did with QTP.  Without an Automation Delegate for the 3rd party components or the automation libraries compiled into the SWF; you aren't going to be able to automate it.

Comment: so there is no possible of adding any plug-in  to any automation tool to make the tool to recognize the flex app?

Comment: Well, not without the source code.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Then what this "use automation at run time" [link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=functest_components2_05.html#195824). whether it is also require the source code or it is any limitation? can you help me out here?

Comment: Fantastic information.  Did you try it; and what were your results?  Basically, you'll have to create a Flex App w/ the automation libraries which does nothing but loads the one w/o the automation libraries.  If you need help building that; feel free to contact me privately to discuss consulting rates. (Or Better yet, contact GorillaLogic the makers of Flex Monkey; as they have specific expertise in the Flex testing domain & do consulting).  It will not solve the issue w/ the third party components that do not have automation delegates, though.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com but is there any other solution like the "run time loading" is available to solve this issue or we need to develop it? any drawback in "run time loading"?

Comment: I'm unaware of any other solution; I didn't even think of the "run time loading" one.  The drawback is that loading a SWF inside another SWF is not quite the same as loading a SWF directly.  I think the security sandbox is slightly different; and some things don't work the same.  But, I've never done that explicitly, so I'm not sure exactly what is different.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and tested a few test frameworks as part of proof of concept ..UFT, QTP and Ranorex ..

Out of all Ranorex is a definite winner ..
It requires minimum dependency ..and minimum coding required ..

Object detection, and maintenance of object  repository is relatively cleaner and simpler.

Test code is generated in c# .net which allows the script being included in a CI environment.

ranorex
http://www.ranorex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have evaluated Test Complete for Flex application and its awesome. You don't have to compile the flex code with automation library. Only thing you need to Flash Player with Debugger on your machine.